# Ubuntu 14.04 upgrade to 16.04 stuck mid install

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, upgrade

I am currently midway through my upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04, and I had the installer terminal prompter inform me that I had made changes to a system file, and whether to install the 16.04 version, keep my current version, exam the differences or open a terminal text editor to make changes there.

The option i received was similar to the following:

```
Configuration file '/etc/sysctl.conf'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** sysctl.conf (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxQn8.png) is bottom of the terminal prompt I am taken to:

I opted to examine the differences, and having been satisfied with what I am seeing in the file, I would like to return to the install and choose the option to install the 16.04 version. There are no instructions on this 'examine differences' page to tell me how to return to the options page. What is the command/process I need to continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I've never done a graphical upgrade)

This will be the outcome of a `diff` command to show you the differences; the `(END)` at the bottom implies that it's been piped through `less`.

You can probably get out of this by using the command to quit `less`, which is `q`.

Comment: Your advice worked. I know this was a pretty noob question but you don't know if you don't know right? Thanks @nickgrim!